# How to replace the SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("Some String") with a file source

Tags: java, encryption, aes, secret-key

I am using SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("some String") to encrypt/dycrypt a string.But I am using  SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("some String") as the key , but I need to use the String key from a file name and that file instance I need to pass inside the SecretKeyFactory.getInstance() method which I can't do.

```
  SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");// here i need to replace
  SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(keyFis.toString());
  char[] password = "Pass@word1".toCharArray();
  byte[] salt = "S@1tS@1t".getBytes("UTF-8");

  KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);
  SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
  byte[] encoded = tmp.getEncoded();
  return new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
```

I am doing

```
  // reading the key 
  String fileName = "C://somewhere//aesKey.dat";
  FileInputStream keyFis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  byte[] encKey = new byte[keyFis.available()];
  keyFis.read(encKey);
  keyFis.close();

  SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(keyFis.toString());
  char[] password = "Pass@word1".toCharArray();
  byte[] salt = "S@1tS@1t".getBytes("UTF-8");

  KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);
  SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
  byte[] encoded = tmp.getEncoded();
  return new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
```

But I am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: java.io.FileInputStream@5ea75ea7 SecretKeyFactory not available
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at test.Main.generateKey(Main.java:66)
at test.Main.getCipher(Main.java:42)
at test.Main.Encrypt(Main.java:30)
at test.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

How to solve this

Comment: What lines of code specifically are the problem?

Comment: Replace `keyFis.toString()` with `new String(encKey)`

Answer (score 1):

If `C:\\somewhere\\aesKey.dat` contains the AES key, then you can read the file into a `byte[]` and directly create a `Key` from that, because a [`SecretKeySpec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html) implements the `Key` interface.

```
String fileName = "C:\\somewhere\\aesKey.dat";
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
return new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
```

Make sure that you import [`java.nio.file.*`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-tree.html).

---

Never use `FileInputStream#available` to determine the size of the file. The returned size can be smaller than the actual file, because the reader is buffered.